# Get transfer function of a nonlinear diff. equation

Tags: taylor-expansion, laplace-transform, nonlinear-system

I have this equation:

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = -g + c\left(u(t) - v(t)\right)^2$$

**g** and **c** are constants. **u(t)** is my input and **v(t)** is my output. I need to reach the transfer function $\frac{V(s)}{U(s)}$ at Laplace domain. In the way the equation is, I think I just can't do it, so I have to linearize it. I read that I can use Taylor series, but I'm getting stucked... How can I get this transfer function?

Some info:

$v(0) = 0 \\ if \ \ u(t) = k, v(t) = 0$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

$$
v'(t)=-g+c u^2(t)-2 c u(t) v (t)+c v^2(t)
$$
This is a [Riccati's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation), of the form 
$$
   v'(t) = q_0(t) + q_1(t) \, v(t) + q_2(t) \, v^2(t) 
$$
where $q_0(t)= -g+c u^2(t)\neq 0$, $q_1(t)=-2 c u(t)$ and  $q_2(t)=c\neq 0$.